# Помогите найти проблему с Karma

Tags: юнит-тесты, jasmine, karma

Мой код!!!

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Girish";
    $scope.sayHello = function () {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
    }
})
```

А Unit test выглядит так:

```
    describe('MainController', function() {
 var controller, scope;
 beforeEach(function(){
     module('myApp');
     inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
    var  scope =  $rootScope.$new();
    var  controller = $controller('MainController', { $scope: scope });
     });
 });
   it("create $scope greeting", function(){
   scope.name = "Girish";
   scope.sayHello();
   expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("Hello Girish");
});

});
```

После закуска "Karma start" у меня вот такая ошибка.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Comment: var внутри inject зачем?

Comment: я попробовала без var , но опять дает ошибку. ReferenceError: scope is not defined

Comment: a $rootscop не должен быть $rootScope? и scop должен быть scope. Очень много ошибок в названии переменных

Comment: А сейчас дает вот такую ошибку. TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Обновите вопрос со всеми внесенными изменениями. Мы не в шахматы играем. У меня не все ходы записаны

Comment: ну var из inject уберите то :(